# Angularfire2 get a key of added object

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, key, angularfire2

Am I able to get a key of just added object?

For example:

```
items.push(
  { ... }
).then(_ => console.log(key of the object));
```

Comment: Maybe you can find the last inserted index like this: console.log(items[items.length - 1]);

Comment: It's a bit dangerous when a lot of people add their own object at the same time. By the way I found that in then(_ => ...) there is a callback like _.path.o[1] (it is a key of added object) :)

Comment: I would suggest using the standard Firebase SDK when you need to do this.

Answer (score 3):

```
items.push(
  { ... }
).then(_ => console.log('Added item key is ', _.key));
```

Please try like this.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean Firebase 3 (AngularFire's `$firebaseArray` has a `$add` to replace `push`) then it returns a reference that is also a "thenable", checkout the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push)

So you can get the `key` of the reference even synchronously:

```
var thenableRef = dataRef.push({someKey: 'some value'});
var newItemKey = thenableRef.$key;
thenableRef.then(_ => console.log('There\'s my new key: %s', newItemKey));
```